# How to I pass IP address of domain name along with domain name in LDAP Authentication?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

How to I pass IP address of domain name along with domain name in LDAP Authentication? With multiple domain authentication I am getting error with domain : The server is not operational

```
    string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
    entry.Username = domainAndUsername;
    entry.Password = pwd;
    object obj = entry.NativeObject;

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";   
    search.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "cn" });
    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

Comment: Please share what you're providing the input for `path` variable in the code. You can straightaway put your AD server's hardcoded IP-Address/hostname in your code (if required)!

Answer (score 1):

You would do it in the path of the `DirectoryEntry` object you're using as the [`SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot). You can do something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.0.0.1");
```

Assuming that server is a domain controller, you will end up searching that domain. There is no need to use the actual name of the domain. If you need to search a specific OU of that domain, you can do it like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.0.0.1/OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

Microsoft has an article on all the different ways you can format that string: [LDAP ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/ldap-adspath)